# How to store ISO/IEC 19794-2 finger print template in postgreSQL database

Tags: java, postgresql, fingerprint, iso

I am building one biometric authentication application. I have successfully generated the finger print template data in console. I am getting these templates in `ISO/IEC 19794-2` format. I just want to know that
is there a way to store the `ISO/IEC 19794-2` finger print template in postgreSQL database ? What can be the data type ?

I have followed their official website but no hint.
I am using `ISO/IEC 19794-2` finger print template for storage and verification purpose.

**EDIT:**
I have 3M CSD200 scanner for getting the finger print template and I am using their SDK to build this application. They have used one algorithm `matchIso19794_2Templates(byte[], byte[])` in which it accept two templates in byte array form and identifies whether they are same or not.

Comment: I'd store something like this as `bytea`, a binary blob, unless you expect to be querying it within the DB in some manner. In that case I'd probably still use `bytea` and write some C functions to act on it, because it's hard to imagine SQL being efficient for this. But the spec does say there is a "record-based format" so you could presumably use that...

Comment: Do you want to match fingerprints  with SQL query ?

Comment: @LaurentY Yea I also want the verification

Comment: @CraigRinger How would you put the verification process once you have the template in binary blob. Because I think template data will vary by generating the finger print template each time

Comment: @Lokesh match fingerprint cannot be done by matching byte array of templates. Please read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint . It can only be done with a specific fingerprint matching algorithm to compare list of minutiae in template

Comment: @LaurentY yea i already visited that link but what can the possible solution for storing and verification ?

Comment: So you expect to be doing matching within the DB? In that case no, you definitely can't just use bytea.

Comment: @LaurentY I have 3M CSD200 scanner for getting the finger print template and I am using their SDK to build this application. They are using one algorithm matchIso19794_2Templates(byte[], byte[]) in which it accept two templates in byte array form and identifies whether they are same or not

Comment: @CraigRinger Is their any efficient way to store the template and then verify it ? Because what I have seen in few Neurotechnology biometric sdks they have use sqlite for enrolling.

Comment: @CraigRinger Why can't we use bytea in this case ? LaurentY has used this method in his answer.

Comment: @Lokesh If it's total equality, you can. I thought you wanted to do heuristic/partial matching or something where the data couldn't be tested for simple equality. Per LaurentY's comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store fingerprint template in database in multiple ways:

1. Large object

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/largeobjects.html

2. bytea

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-binary.html

3. in hexa (for small data)

You could convert your byte array to hexa, and store string

To compare, fingerprints there's two cases:

1. Compare 1 to 1

You could use method `matchIso19794_2Templates(byte[], byte[])` provide by your SDK

2. Compare 1 to n

You could use an [AFIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Automated_Fingerprint_Identification_System)

Comment: Craig in the above comments said we can't use bytea for matching within the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm [available in public](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#!iso:std:50864:en) for comparing ISO/IEC 19794-2 templates is incomplete. With the help of them, it would be difficult to get the comparison implemented at the server. 3rd party services are available for the comparing fingerprints through web services, you have to rely on following vendors or you have to implement your own automated finger identification system on your server or you have to compare at the devices through [client side scripts (like javascript)](http://camsunit.com/application/javascript-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html)

1. [CAMS](http://camsunit.com/application/javascript-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html#compare-fingerprint)
2. [M2Sys](http://www.m2sys.com)
3. [Neurotechnology](https://www.neurotechnology)